# Prove the metric of $\ell_2$ satisfies the triangle-inequality

Tags: real-analysis, limits, inequality, metric-spaces, triangle-inequality

**Problem**: Prove the metric of $\ell_2$ satisfies the triangle-inequality

> **Reminders**:
>
> - A point in $ \ell_2 $ space is an infinite sequence $ \mathbf x = \langle x_k \rangle_{k=1}^{\infty} $ of real numbers, for which $ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x_k^2 < \infty $, meaning the infinite series $  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x_k^2  $ converges.
> - The distance between $ \mathbf x = \langle x_k \rangle $ to $ \mathbf y = \langle y_k \rangle $ in $ \ell_2 $ is defined as such:
>   $ d(\mathbf x,\mathbf y) :=  \sqrt{ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} ( x_k - y_k )^2 } $

> **Proof from the book:** Let $ \mathbf x = \langle x_k \rangle _k , y = \langle y_k \rangle _k , z = \langle z_k \rangle _k   $ be arbitrary points in $ \ell_2 $. Let $ n  $ be natural number. We'll use the triangle-inequality satisfied by the Euclidian metrics and the fact that all the elements of the sums are positive so that we'll have:
> $ \sqrt{ \sum_{k=1}^{n} ( x_k - z_k )^2 }  \leq  \sqrt{ \sum_{k=1}^{n} ( x_k - y_k )^2 } + \sqrt{ \sum_{k=1}^{n} ( y_k - z_k )^2 }   \leq  \sqrt{ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} ( x_k - y_k )^2 } + \sqrt{ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} ( y_k - z_k )^2 } = d( \mathbf x, \mathbf y ) + d( \mathbf y, \mathbf z )  $
> When $ n \rightarrow \infty $ on the left-hand side of the inequality, the inequality is preserved and we get
> $ d( \mathbf x, \mathbf z ) = d( \mathbf x, \mathbf y ) + d( \mathbf y, \mathbf z )   $.

**My question:**
In the proof from the book, I understood everything until where they've decided to take the limit $ n \rightarrow \infty  $ on the left-hand side of the inequality.
I denoted $ A_n = \sqrt{ \sum_{k=1}^{n} ( x_k - z_k )^2 }  $ , $ B_n = \sqrt{ \sum_{k=1}^{n} ( x_k - y_k )^2 } $ , $ C_n = \sqrt{ \sum_{k=1}^{n} ( y_k - z_k )^2 }  $, I know $ A_n \leq B_n + C_n  $ and also that $ A_n \leq \lim_{ k \rightarrow \infty }( B_k + C_k) $ ( since our sums are of positive numbers only ) .
However, I don't understand why the inequality when taking limit on left side : $ \lim_{ n \rightarrow \infty } A_n \leq \lim_{ n \rightarrow \infty }( B_n + C_n) $ is justified? ( because maybe $ \lim_{ n \rightarrow \infty } A_n $ does not converge or is $ +\infty $ ,  while $ \lim_{ n \rightarrow \infty }( B_n + C_n)  $ converges to constant number ).

***Note***: I'm familiar with taking limits on inequalities in Real-Analysis. If we have sequences $a_{n}, b_{n}$ with $a_{n} < b_{n}$ and both the sequences converge to $a, b$ respectively then from this information we can only conclude that $a \leq b$. But the example above undermined my understanding.

Comment: My own question: $ \sqrt{ \sum_{k=1}^{n} ( x_k - z_k )^2 }  \leq  \sqrt{ \sum_{k=1}^{n} ( x_k - y_k )^2 } + \sqrt{ \sum_{k=1}^{n} ( y_k - z_k )^2 }\ $. Why can't you just say that, at this stage, taking the limit as $\ n\to\infty\ $ yields the result?

Comment: Because I don't know if the left-hand side and the right-hand side converge

Comment: Yes you do. Since $x,y,z$ are points in the metric space, $d(x,y), d(x,z),$ and $d(y,z)$ must all exist.

Comment: In that case, I can immediately take $ n \rightarrow \infty $ on the inequality $ \sqrt{ \sum_{k=1}^{n} ( x_k - z_k )^2 }  \leq  \sqrt{ \sum_{k=1}^{n} ( x_k - y_k )^2 } + \sqrt{ \sum_{k=1}^{n} ( y_k - z_k )^2 }\ $ and that'll yield the result, makes sense now. I missed the fact that the distances exist

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking...Why didn't the author just do that instead?

Comment: The book is about point-set topology and it doesn't remind any prerequisites for Linear Algebra ( which is necessary since Vector Spaces , Norms and Inner-products are interweaved in the subject of metric spaces ), but it does remind Real-Analysis as a prerequisite instead, so I just dived in. I guess I should learn more Linear Algebra before proceeding any further in the book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\ell_2$ is a vector space, $\sum_{k=1}^\infty(x_k-z_k)^2<\infty$. Besides, the sequence $\left(\sum_{k=1}^n(x_k-z_k)^2\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is an increasing one. So (and since it is bounded) it is convergent.